# Make it so document generated by JS can be saved to disk

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am using the following code to print generated code into a new window:

```
var myWindow = window.open('lib/dummy.php', 'myWindow', '');
myWindow.document.write(html_content);
myWindow.document.close();
```

I would now like to save the generated document to the local file system (or allow the user to do so if he or she wishes using the File menu for instance). I would also like the address URL to be "https://website.com/lib/dummy.php". However in Google Chrome the address bar says "about:blank" and the "Save as" command is greyed out. In Mozilla Firefox the URL of the new window is the same as the document that opened the new window. I do not like this either. How do I fix these issues?

Comment: First, you have no access to save things to the user's file system, except via things like `localStorage`, cookies etc. Secondly, you have no control over the URL shown in a new, URL-less window. Chrome's `about:blank` seems the more intuitive to me; it's literally a blank document. Firefox seems to prefer to show the owner (opener) document.

Comment: Don't use popups, nobody likes them and most browsers block them by default. Serve the content from the server as a file. This way you'll get the normal download interaction.

Comment: The generated page also pulls CSS, images, etc. from the server. I cannot serve just one single file.